# Django bulk create with foreign key to another field

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I want to bulk create objects, when they have a foreign key and their foreign key is not id field. (When to_field value is `id` you can reference it with `model_id` in creation but I haven't found a way to do id with another field.)

I have a model named Credit:

```
class Credit(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey('finance.Account', to_field='account_id', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    amount = models.PositiveBigIntegerField()
```

and a model named Account:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    account_id = models.UUIDField(
        verbose_name=_("account id"),
        db_index=True,
        null=True,
        unique=True,
    )
```

and I tried to create objects with:

```
accounts = [] # list of uuids

 credits = [
            Credit(
                account__account_id=a, 
                amount=amount, 
            ) for a in accounts]
        created_objects = Credit.objects.bulk_create(
            credits, ignore_conflicts=True
        )
```

and I get the following error:

> TypeError: Credit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'account__account_id'

Comment: It should work with `account_id` as usual. Did you try `Credit(account_id=a)`?

Comment: `credits = [Credit(account_id=a, amount=amount) for a in accounts]`

Comment: @neverwalkaloner @ThiernoAmadouSow  I want to query base on `account_id` column, not `id` column in Account.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible because you are touching two tables: `Credit` and `Account`. So you need at least two `INSERT`s anyways.

```
accounts_uuids = []
amount = 0

accounts = [Account(account_id=uuid) for uuid in accounts_uuids]
Account.objects.bulk_create(objs=accounts)

credits = [Credit(account=account, amount=amount) for account in accounts]
Credit.objects.bulk_create(objs=credits, ignore_conflicts=True)
```